# Compare two data frames to return True or False

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I need to create function which will return True or False, when value from first data frame is equal to value from second data frame.

```
df1 (Look up dataframe)
  root
 |-- Customer_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Customer_Name: string (nullable = true)

df2 (in coming data frame)
 root
 |-- CustomerID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CustomerName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ZipCode: double (nullable = true)
 |-- State: string (nullable = true)

df1.id [123, 234, 345, 456, 567]
df2.id [123, 567]

def fn_new_function(df1, df2):
   is_same = df2.join(df1,df2('CustomerID') == df1('Customer_ID'), how='inner') \
            .where(df2['CustomerName'] == df1['Customer_Name'])\ 
            .count() == df2.count()

   if is_same.count() > 0:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Following error is ....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/---/process_files.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "/---/process_files.py", line 456, in fn_new_function
    is_same = df2.join(df1,df2('id')!=df1('c_id'), how='inner') \
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is your desired output? What are you trying to do? Seems like using a `join` would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data frames have the same schema, you can substract and check that the result is empty:

```
is_same = df1.subtract(df2).count() == 0
```

If you just want to check that all `id` fields from both data frames match (different schema), you can just compare DFs of ID fields:

```
is_same = df1.select('id').subtract(df2.select('id')).count() == 0
```

Note that this doesn't take order into account.

To verify that all records in `df2` match the name defined in `df1`, then you can use a join and a filter:

```
is_same = df2.join(df1, on='id', how='inner')\
             .where(df1['CustomerName'] == df2['CustomerName'])\
             .count() == df2.count()
```

This version does an inner join and filters out anything that does not have a matching name in the 2 data frames. The assumption is that the resulting count would be the same as total records in `df2` if all names match.

Comment: I have added schema for both data frames in my question.

Comment: And you're checking all record in `df2`? (if lookup name of all customers in df2 match, then return true)?

Comment: Yes df2 is in coming record, I will check all records df1 which is kind of look up(view) and when I find first occurrence in df1, function should return True, when no record found in df1, return False.

Comment: thanks for your time and patience, I modify my function I am getting error message... not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @SM `is_same` is a boolean. The function should just return it, not call `.count` on it

Answer (score 0):

```
def fn_new_function(df1, df2):

   df1.show()
   df2.show()

   is_same = df1.join(df2,df1('Customer_ID') == df2('CustomerID'), how='inner') \
            .where(df1['Customer_Name'] == df2['CustomerName'])

   if is_same.count() > 0:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```